# libPods google map iOS , Install

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, frameworks, cocoapods

I have This code in Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'Kine' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

I want Install in Terminal

```
cd /Users/-----
pod Install
```

I received this error

**[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 11.0 on target because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.**

and in the site I see iOS 10.6 but I don't have iOS 10.6 in Xcode when I change the target in iOS 8.0 or 9.0 or 10 it's not work again and received the same error

and the libPods.a its missing (Red)

Comment: this is not an error its just warning

Comment: and for the libPods.a its missing, did you open you project with file name say YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace????

Comment: @Muhammed Irfan I try to open the Xcode with Xcode project

Comment: how can I open with .xcworkspace

Comment: goto your root folder of project

Comment: see there will be file with .xcworkspace extension

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open terminal
2. type

> sudo gem install cocoapods

1. create Podfile in your project root directory
2. Open Podfile
3. Type

> ```
> platform :ios, '10.0'
>
> use_frameworks!
>
> target 'Kine' do
>
>     pod 'GoogleMaps'
>     pod 'GooglePlaces'
> end
> ```

1. open terminal goto: cd /Users/path/to/project/root
2. type **pod Install** and press enter
3. goto your project root using Finder
4. open file Kine.xcworkspace
5. Run your project